# SpringBoot 1.5.10.RELEASE: REST service keeps geting 404

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm seeing dozens of similar posts but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. I have a WAR with the following structure:

The folder "controller" contains a REST controller having the following code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HmlRestController
{
  ...........
  @RequestMapping(value = "/myResource/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<?> myResource(@RequestBody HmlEvent hmlEvent)
  {
    ..........
  }
}
```

The application.properties file has the following entry:

```
server.context-path=/hml
```

Running the WAR in Tomcat embedded and going to localhost:8080/hml displays the index.html file but trying to **POST to localhost:8080/hml/api/myResource** returns HTTP 404.
If I move this code into the HmlApplication class, like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HmlApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(HmlApplication.class, args);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/myResource/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<?> myResource(@RequestBody HmlEvent hmlEvent)
  {
    ..........
  }`enter code here`
}
```

then it works as expected. 
Could someone please shed some lights here and let me know what is going on here ?
Many thanks in advance,
Nicolas

Comment: Is you controller located in a subpackage of the application class package ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've tried to insert an image showing the package hierarchy but, for some reason, it didn't work. So yes, the HmlApplication class is in com.tests while the controller class is in com.tests.controllers.

Answer (score 2):

By using Spring Boot and its `@SpringBootApplication`, you automatically enable component scanning (see `@ComponentScan` on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation).

You didn't mention your package structure, but your other package hierarchies should be below your main app with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, `HmlApplication` in your case.

You can add packages explicitly by adding an extra `@ComponentScan` annotation to your application class.

```
@ComponentScan(“my.package”)
@SpringBootApplication
public class HmlApplication {
```

Comment: Yes, this is the case, the HmlApplication class is at the root of the package hierarchy. I don't need to add other packages. However, the controller isn't found and I keep being given 404.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what happened but restarting everything solved the issue. The only thing I could think at is that, during the IntelliJ session, some message saying something about several Spring contexts has been displayed and I choose the default action. But I'm not any more sure. So for now, I'm closing this issue.
Kind regards,
Nicolas